# How do I optimize this algorithm so it doesn't exceed the given time limit?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, math, set

First of all, I'm trying to solve the following problem using Python:

> An arithmetic progression is a sequence of the form a, a+b, a+2b, ..., a+nb
> where n=0, 1, 2, 3, ... . For this problem, a is a non-negative integer and b is a positive integer.
>
> Write a program that finds all arithmetic progressions of length n in the set S of bisquares.
> The set of bisquares is defined as the set of all integers of the form p<sup>2</sup> + q<sup>2</sup>
> (where p and q are non-negative integers).
>
> Time limit: 5 seconds
>
> **Input format:**
> Line 1:   N (3 <= N <= 25), the length of progressions for which to search
> Line 2: M (1 <= M <= 250), an upper bound to limit the search to the bisquares with 0 <= p,q <= M.
>
> **Sample input:**
>
> ```
> 5
> 7
> ```
>
> **Output format:**
> If no sequence is found, a single line reading `NONE`.
> Otherwise, output one or more lines, each with two integers:
> the first element in a found sequence and the difference between consecutive elements in the same sequence.
> The lines should be ordered with smallest-difference sequences first and smallest starting number within those sequences first.
>
> There will be no more than 10,000 sequences.
>
> **Sample output:**
>
> ```
> 37 4
> 2 8
> 29 8
> 1 12
> 5 12
> 13 12
> 17 12
> 5 20
> 2 24
> ```

The code I've written does work, but it exceeds the given time limit by a wide margin. I can't tell if it's a problem caused by the algorithm itself or just Python. Can someone suggest a way to make this run under 5 seconds? Here's the code:

```
fin = open ('ariprog.in', 'r')
fout = open ('ariprog.out', 'w')

N:int=int(fin.readline().strip())#take N
M:int=int(fin.readline().strip())#take M

s:set=set()#set s 
ans:list=[]#the list that will contain the pairs
mx:int=M**2 * 2#absolute max value in the set s 

for j in range(M+1):#produce the set s 
    for i in range(j,M+1):
        h:int=(i**2)+(j**2)
        s.add(h)

for stepVal in range(1,(mx//(N-1))+1):#iterates over the possible step values
    for initial in s:#iterates over the possible starting points in the set s
        count:int=1
        k:int=initial
        while count<N:
            if k+stepVal not in s:break #if the loop breaks, 
            k+=stepVal                  #we don't add the pair to the answer list
            count+=1
        else:ans.append([initial,stepVal])
ans.sort(key=lambda x:x[1]) #sort the answer list
if not ans:fout.write("NONE" + "\n")
for i,e in ans:
    pr=f'{str(i)} {str(e)}\n'
    fout.write(pr)
fout.close()
```

When presented with test case 7, I get the following message:

```
  > Run 7: Execution error: Your program (`ariprog') used more than
        the allotted runtime of 5 seconds (it ended or was stopped at
        5.242 seconds) when presented with test case 7. It used 10368 KB
        of memory. 

        ------ Data for Run 7 [length=7 bytes] ------
        21 
        200 
        ----------------------------
```

Comment: Can you provide the correct output for 'test case 7'?

Comment: 1217 84
2434 168
4868 336
6085 420
9736 672
10953 756
12170 840
12953 924
15821 1092 Note that they're given in pairs

Comment: you could remove lines where you defined variables to save memory, and how comes you need to declare what type of variable it is.

Comment: The [sum of two squares theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem) implies that if `a` and `b` are both bisquares, then `a*b` is also a bisquare. This would imply that if `(a, b)` is a solution, then `(s*a, s*b)` is a solution as well for `s in S` provided that `s*(a+n*b)` doesn’t become too large, You could use this to find a whole range of solutions once you find one.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop can be optimized - but it will require a bit more logic.

The idea is that after checking `initial` you will depending on result either know that `initial+stepVal` will not have a sequence either, or that you don't have to check the first `N-1` numbers (as they were already checked).

And you seem to generate the result in order, so no need to sort them.

Comment: But stepVal changes. How would I know if a different sequence with a different stepVal starting at some initial exists without actually checking?

Comment: You will not know it for a different stepVal - but for the same one stepVal, with a new initial - specifically the old initial+stepVal.

Answer (score 0):

I removed variable defining to save memory

I also used list comprehensions where possible.

```
fin = open ('ariprog.in', 'r')
fout = open ('ariprog.out', 'w')



ans:list=[]#the list that will contain the pairs

s = set([(i**2)+(j**2) for j in range(int(fin.readline().strip())+1) for i in range(j,int(fin.readline().strip())+1)])

for stepVal in range(1,(int(fin.readline().strip())**2 * 2//(int(fin.readline().strip())-1))+1):#iterates over the possible step values
    for initial in s:#iterates over the possible starting points in the set s
        count:int=1
        k:int=initial
        while count<int(fin.readline().strip()):
            if k+stepVal not in s:break #if the loop breaks,
            k+=stepVal                  #we don't add the pair to the answer list
            count+=1
        else:ans.append([initial,stepVal])
ans.sort(key=lambda x:x[1]) #sort the answer list

if not ans:fout.write("NONE" + "\n")


[fout.write (f'{str(i)} {str(e)}\n') for i,e in ans]
fout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

What could speed it up a little bit is to approach the solution as a progressive refinement/filter of the whole set of bisquares for each step size. This can cut the execution time by roughly 20%

However, I found that the real speed boost could comes from a conjecture (that I haven't been able to prove yet) where only striding steps that are multiples of 4 can exist in sequences of 4 or more elements.

```
def findSequences(N,M,step=4):
    S       = { p*p+q*q for p in range(M+1) for q in range(p,M+1) }
    if N<4 : step = 1
    for b in range(step,2*M*M//(N-1)+1,step):
        eligible = S
        for n in range(1,N):
            eligible = eligible.intersection(e-b for e in eligible)
            if not eligible: break            
        for a in sorted(eligible):
            yield a,b
            
print(*findSequences(5,7) )

# (1, 4) (37, 4) (2, 8) (29, 8) (1, 12) (5, 12) (13, 12) (17, 12) (5, 20) (2, 24)

print(*findSequences(21,200) )

# (1217, 84) (2434, 168) (4868, 336) (6085, 420) (9736, 672) (10953, 756) (12170, 840) (12953, 924) (15821, 1092)
```

*On my laptop, this conjecture cuts the execution time by 75%*

Perhaps someone with deeper knowledge of number theory can shed some light on my hypothesis about multiples of 4.

Even though I can't explain why it does, the conjecture works for M <= 250, as demonstrated by:

```
all(b%4==0 for a,b in findSequences(4,250,1)) # returns True
```

And since longer sequences are extensions of the shorter ones, it will hold true for N = 5,6,7, ...

Comment: Part of that is that: Numbers mod 4 can be 0,1,2,3; squared that gives 0,1,0,1; and thus mod 4 the sum of two squares can only be 0,1,2 - not 3. That means the stride cannot be odd for a sequence of 4 or more.